# all form controls are valid but the form is invalid in angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I created an asyc validator for my registration form, and connected it to my express app so that it returns the right response, now I'm in the last step where all the form controls are valid but the form itself doesn't get validated and the submit button stays disabled, here is my code

**register.component.ts**

```typescript
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
    import { UniqueEmail } from '../validators/unique-email';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-register',
      templateUrl: './register.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss'],
    })
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit{
      registerForm: FormGroup
      constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private auth: AuthService,
       private uniqueEmail: UniqueEmail
      ) {}
    
      ngOnInit(){
        this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
          firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
          lastName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
          email: [
            null,
            [Validators.required, Validators.email],
            this.uniqueEmail.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this.uniqueEmail)
          ],
          phoneNumber: [null, Validators.required],
          password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
        });
      
    
        this.registerForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data =>  {
          const invalid = [];
          const controls = this.registerForm.controls;
          for (const name in controls) {
              if (controls[name].invalid) {
                  invalid.push(name);
              }
          }
    
          console.log (invalid);
          console.log(this.registerForm.valid)
      });
    
      }
    
      onSubmit() {
        this.auth.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(console.log);
      }
    }
```

**register.component.html**

```html
    <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-card class="shipping-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>Manager Registration</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input
                  matInput
                  placeholder="First name"
                  formControlName="firstName"
                  type="text"
                />
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('minlength')"
                >
                  min length is 2 characters
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('required')"
                >
                  First name is <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input
                  matInput
                  placeholder="Last name"
                  formControlName="lastName"
                  type="text"
                />
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('minlength')"
                >
                  min length is 2 characters
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('required')"
                >
                  Last name is <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input
                  matInput
                  placeholder="Email"
                  formControlName="email"
                  type="email"
                />
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['email'].hasError('required')"
                >
                  Email is <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error
                *ngIf="registerForm.controls['email'].hasError('emailTaken')"
              >
                this email is used before
              </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['email'].hasError('email')">
                  please enter a valid email
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input
                  matInput
                  placeholder="Phone Number"
                  formControlName="phoneNumber"
                  type="text"
                />
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['phoneNumber'].hasError('required')"
                >
                  Phone Number is <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input
                  matInput
                  placeholder="Password"
                  formControlName="password"
                  type="password"
                />
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['password'].hasError('required')"
                >
                  Password is <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error
                  *ngIf="registerForm.controls['password'].hasError('minlength')"
                >
                  min length is 8 characters
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button
            mat-raised-button
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            [disabled]="!registerForm.valid"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </form>
```

**auth.service.ts**

```typescript
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class AuthService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    
      registerUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/manager/register`;
      loginUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/manager/login`;
      checkEmailNotTakenUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/manager/unique-email`;
    
      register(formInfo) {
        return this.http.post(this.registerUrl, formInfo);
      }
    
      login(formInfo) {
        return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, formInfo).pipe(
          map((result) => {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', result['token']);
            return result;
          })
        );
      }
    
      logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
      }
    
      public get loggedIn(): boolean {
        return localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== null;
      }
    
      checkEmailNotTaken(email) {
        return this.http.post(this.checkEmailNotTakenUrl, { email: email });
      }
    }
```

**unique-email.ts**

```typescript
    import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class UniqueEmail {
      constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}
    
      validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl) {
        return this.auth.checkEmailNotTaken(control.value).pipe(
          tap(console.log),
          map((res) => {
            return res == { emailTaken: true } ? null : { emailTaken: true };
          }),
          tap(console.log),
        );
      }
    }
```

this photo summarizes the problem where the array contains the invalid controls and the Boolean represents the validity of the form
[app inteface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxuQg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by checking form control validators in the disabled submit button but I still don't know what was the real cause of the problem

```
[disabled]="registerForm.controls['password'].hasError('minlength') || registerForm.controls['password'].hasError('required') || registerForm.controls['phoneNumber'].hasError('required') || registerForm.controls['email'].hasError('email') || registerForm.controls['email'].hasError('emailTaken') || registerForm.controls['email'].hasError('required') || registerForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('required') || registerForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('minlength') || registerForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('required') || registerForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('minlength')"
```